# In what ways can a BackgroundService get stopped?

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, background-service

I developed a REST API using .NET 6. This API (running on a windows server system) has a background process by implementing a class inheriting from the `BackgroundService`  class. The only method of this class  I implemented myself is `ExecuteAsync`. It has a loop containing a delay using the cancellationToken.

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        .....   
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            ....
            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
            .....
        }
        .....
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ........ 
        _logger.LogError(e.GetBaseException(),"Failed processing requested numbers");
        throw;
    }
}
```

What becomes clear from the logs (caught exception) is that the cancellation token was used to cancel the process. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0), this would mean a “graceful shutdown”.  However, what also becomes clear from the logs is that the application just keeps on running (lots of requests are logged afterwards). Logically, a “shutdown” would affect the whole application but that is simply not happening.

Thus, in what ways can a BackgroundService get stopped? Apparently, there are more ways then a "graceful shutdown". What are those other ways? This is very frustrating because now it looks like my background process is sometimes stopped magically.

Comment: At least this code sample would only run once on a specific set of values and then end. Is there some system that should keep it alive forever? Or is `numbers` some generator or blocking iterator or…?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, the for loop is part of a while loop but that is not relevant for my question. The cancallation comes from somewhere. And I do not understand what that somewhere could be.

Comment: You can use `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` in while loop, something like this:

`while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
 // something that should stop in some case
}`

Edit: Or in your case, more relevant will be using for loop with additional condition of stopping it:

```for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested; i++) {
                var number = numbers[i];

                // do something with number
            }```

Comment: Graceful shutdown means the application is allowed to finish any pending work. That includes background services *and* requests. The app will only abort the pending work if shutdown takes too long. As for when it's triggered, that happens when the [IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-hosting-ihostapplicationlifetime-stopapplication) is called, in response to an IIS command, a service command or a CLI keystroke

Comment: That will trigger any subscribed CancellationTokenSource isntances which in turn will trigger their tokens and any other chained CTSs. It's up to the application code to respect the tokens though. If something is busy doing some work and only inspects the token after 30s, shutdown will take at least 30s.

Comment: So it's the opposite of *the cancellation token was used to cancel the process*. The process went into the Stopping mode and triggered the tokens

Comment: _"What becomes clear from the logs (caught exception) is that the cancellation token was used to cancel the process"_ - how have you determined that?  "Cancelation" exception can happen for multiple reasons, for example some timeouts can lead to the same exception. Try adding `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` to your log message to see if it is actually application shutdown which caused this.

Answer (score 0):

The way how you can handle this is to use `CancellationToken cancellationToken` from the `ExecuteAsync` parameter.

You can use this in various way, in your scenario, the easiest way will be checking if it was cancelled.

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    ....
    await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
    .....

    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        break; // break in case of cancellation requested
    }
}
```

You can also use this within different types of loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested; i++) {
    ....
}
```

or

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
   ...
}
```